# Google Maps Api v3 - several Marker hovers with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to set different hovers for different marker icons i use on my map.

This is my marker icon array

```
//Marker Icons
    var markerIcon = {
        unvisitedMarker: {
            url: 'img/marker.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
        },
        unvisitedMarkerHover: {
            url: 'img/marker.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(30, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
        },
        activeMarker: {
            url: 'img/marker.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(60, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
        },
        visitedMarker: {
            url: 'img/marker.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(90, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
        },
        visitedMarkerHover: {
            url: 'img/marker.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(120, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15)
        }
```

I got all icons in one sprite.
I want to set the hover effect for the 'unvisitedMarker' with 'unvisitedMarkerHover' and for 'visitedMarker with 'visitedMarkerHover'. If the marker has the 'activeMarker' icon it should not get a hover effect.

My Problem with this is - i don't know how to set the "if" requirement for that.

```
//marker hover effect
        marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            if (???) { ... }
        });

        marker.addListener('mouseout', function() {
            if (???) { ... }
        });
```

After that i know i can set the icon with:

```
marker.setIcon(markerIcon['unvisitedMarker']);
```

So if someone could help me with the if requirement - that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is not that simple. Since I don't have the details such as the URL to your images, I created a sample application in which we have at least 90% similarity. **Important: Please don't use the images I've used to avoid copyright issues.**

First, I've created public variables: **map**, **markers**. **"markers"** is an empty array.

```
var map; 
var markers = [];
```

I've also created my own version of **markerIcon** object.

```
var markerIcon = {
    url : 'http://oi68.tinypic.com/30idv0z.jpg',
    unvisitedMarkerHover: 'http://oi65.tinypic.com/jgo3r8.jpg',
    originlUrl: 'http://oi68.tinypic.com/30idv0z.jpg',
    visitedMarkerHover: 'http://oi65.tinypic.com/ejbn88.jpg',
    status: {
      unvisitedMarker : {
        statusName: 'unvisitedMarker',
      },
      activeMarker : {
        statusName: 'activeMarker',
      },
      visitedMarker : {    
        statusName: 'visitedMarker',
      }
    }
};
```

I've used a **coordinate** in San Francisco for my map's center and for **[Google Maps Javascript API Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#overview)**. I've used **[Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)** as a **Place Search** and used San Francisco's coordinate for the **location** property. The radius is set to **500** (measured in meters). This is essential as a combination of the **location** property - specifying the center of the circle as a LatLng object. For the types, i restricted it only to **stores**. To learn more about supported types, please check **[list of supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)**.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch({
    location: myLatLng,
    radius: '500',
    type: ['store']
}, callback);
```

In Nearby Search callback, it returns an array of results. This is what I did:

```
function createMarker(place, markerId) {
 var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     id: markerId,
     map: map,
     position: placeLoc,
     title: 'Hello World!',
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15),
     icon: {
       url : markerIcon.url,
     },
     currentStatus: '',
     status: markerIcon.status.unvisitedMarker.statusName,
     size: new google.maps.Size(30,30),
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}  

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i],i);
    }
  }
}
```

- I created a createMarker() function that accepts two arguments: the
  place object, and markerId.
- What the function does is it creates a new **[Google Maps Javascript
  API
  Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)**
  and then set the property and its values accordingly. And also, after
  creating the new **"marker"** object, it will be pushed in to
  **markers** array.
- You will also notice that I've added custom properties:
  currentStatus, and status. This will play a very important role in
  our mouse events.
- Since the callback results is an array, I iterate through each array
  and called createMarker() function.

This is where the fun begins, in createMarker(), I've also added lines for  **[Google Maps Javascript API Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)**. This is what I did on my end. Whenever there's a **mouseover** on a marker, it checks first the **currentStatus** property of the mouseovered marker. If the currentStatus is an empty string **''**, it will do another checking for the **status** property. If the status is **'unvisited'**, the current icon will now change to a new one. When a **mouseout** has been detected, the new icon will change to the original one.

Meanwhile, when a marker is clicked, the **currentStatus** property will be updated to **"activeMarker"** and then the **"status"** property is changed to **"visitedMarker"** as well. You will notice that if the marker has an **"activeMarker"** currentStatus, nothing will happen when there's a mouseover.

In order to remove the **"activeMarker"** currentStatus, you will have to click another marker. The "activeMarker" now is transferred to this "another marker". You will also notice that there's a new mouseover effect on the previous marker because I've set a new icon if the marker's status is "unvisitedMarker". You can all find all icon URLs in the **markerIcon** object.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
     if ( this.currentStatus !== markerIcon.status.activeMarker.statusName ) {
       if ( this.status === markerIcon.status.unvisitedMarker.statusName ) {
         this.setIcon(markerIcon.unvisitedMarkerHover);      
       } else {
         this.setIcon(markerIcon.visitedMarkerHover);            
       }
      this.setPosition(this.position);  
      console.log(this.currentStatus, this.status, this.id);      
     }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      this.setIcon(markerIcon.originlUrl);      
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
       markers[i].currentStatus = '';
     }     
     this.currentStatus = markerIcon.status.activeMarker.statusName;
     this.status = markerIcon.status.visitedMarker.statusName;
     console.log(this.currentStatus, this.status);
  });
```

Whole code below:

```js
var map; 
var markers = [];
var markerIcon = {
    url : 'http://oi68.tinypic.com/30idv0z.jpg',
    unvisitedMarkerHover: 'http://oi65.tinypic.com/jgo3r8.jpg',
    originlUrl: 'http://oi68.tinypic.com/30idv0z.jpg',
    visitedMarkerHover: 'http://oi65.tinypic.com/ejbn88.jpg',
    status: {
      unvisitedMarker : {
        //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        statusName: 'unvisitedMarker',
      },
      activeMarker : {
        //origin: new google.maps.Point(60, 0),
        statusName: 'activeMarker',
      },
      visitedMarker : {    
        //origin: new google.maps.Point(90, 0),
        statusName: 'visitedMarker',
      },
    }
}; 
  

function initMap() {
  
  var myLatLng = {lat: 37.773972, lng: -122.431297};
  
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatLng
  });
  
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: myLatLng,
    radius: '500',
    type: ['store']
  }, callback);
  
}

function createMarker(place, markerId) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: markerId,
        map: map,
        position: placeLoc,
        title: 'Hello World!',
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(15, 15),
        icon: {
          url : markerIcon.url,
        },
        currentStatus: '',
        status: markerIcon.status.unvisitedMarker.statusName,
        size: new google.maps.Size(30,30),
  });
  
  markers.push(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
     if ( this.currentStatus !== markerIcon.status.activeMarker.statusName ) {
       if ( this.status === markerIcon.status.unvisitedMarker.statusName ) {
         this.setIcon(markerIcon.unvisitedMarkerHover);      
       } else {
         this.setIcon(markerIcon.visitedMarkerHover);            
       }
      this.setPosition(this.position);  
      //console.log(this.currentStatus, this.status, this.id);      
     }
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
      this.setIcon(markerIcon.originlUrl);      
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
       markers[i].currentStatus = '';
     }     
     this.currentStatus = markerIcon.status.activeMarker.statusName;
     this.status = markerIcon.status.visitedMarker.statusName;
  });
}   

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i],i);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Hope this application could help and happy coding!